# Combine Python Flask Jinja2 and Mustache

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, mustache

I am using Mustache.js with Flask and jinja2 and have a problem to render images.

I succeeded to render my mustache template in jinja thanks to `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}` but now I need to use `url_for()` from Jinja in my template to define my image source. There is a conflict between the `{{}}` from mustache and the ones from Jinja.

My javascript :

```
target = document.getElementById("target");
var template = $('#my-template').html();
Mustache.parse(template);
var rendered = Mustache.render(template, {"title":"My Title","photo_name":"photo.jpg"});
target.innerHTML = rendered;
```

And my template :

```
<script id="my-template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">
{% raw %}
  <h1> {{title}} </h1>
  <img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='images/{{photo_name}}') }}" alt="my_photo">
{% endraw %}
</script>
```

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expressing `raw` treatment over quite a bit of content, some of which you don't really want to be raw. Suggest you narrow the scope of `{% raw %} ... {% endraw %}` to cover only those template variables you wish Mustache to fill in. For example:

```
<script id="my-template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">

  <h1> {% raw %}{{title}}{% endraw %} </h1>
  <img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='images/')}}{% raw %}{{photo_name}}{% endraw %}" alt="my_photo">

</script>
```

To the browser this will render the following, the template sections of which can then be filled in by JS / Mustache:

```
<script id="my-template" type="x-tmpl-mustache">

  <h1> {{title}} </h1>
  <img src="/static/images/{{photo_name}}" alt="my_photo">

</script>
```

In this way you get Mustache handling specific template substitutions, Flask / Jinja2 handling the rest.

Using two template engines with such interleaved and overlapping responsibilities—not to mention identical template variable marking syntax—makes the "quoting" entirely essential, yet also very nitsy.